# Optimal virtual machine/byte-code interpreter loop

Tags: c++, gcc

My project has a VM that executes a byte-code compiled from a domain-specific-language. I'm looking at ways that I can improve the execution time of the byte-code. As a first step I'd like to see if there is a way to simply improve the byte-code interpreter before I venture into machine code compilation.

The main loop of the interpreter looks like this:

```
while(true)
{
  uint8_t cmd = *code++;
  switch( cmd )
  {
    case op_1: ...; break;
    ...
  }
}
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a faster way to implement this loop without resorting to assembler?

The one option I see is GCC specific to use dynamic goto with label addresses. Rather than a `break` at the end of each case I could jump directly to the next instruction.  I had hoped the optimizer would do this for me, but looking at the disassembly it apparently doesn't: there is a repeated constant jump at the end of most op_codes.

*If relevant the VM is a simple register based machine with floating point and integer registers (8 of each). There is no stack, only a global heap (that language is not that complicated).*

Answer (score 3):

One very easy optimisation is that instead of 
switch /case/case/case/case/case,

just define an array with function pointers (where each function would process a specified command, or a couple of commands in which case you could set several entries in the array to the same function, and the function itself could check the exact code), and instead of

```
switch(cmd)
```

just do a

```
array[cmd]()
```

This is given that you dont have too many commands. Also, do some checking if you will not define all the possible commands (maybe you only have 300 commands, but you have to use 2 bytes for representing them, so instead of definining an array with 65536 items, just check if the command is less than 301 and if its not, dont do the lookup)

If you won't do that, at least sort the commands that the most used ones are in the beginning of the switch statement.

Otherwise it would be to look into hashtables, but I assume you don't have that many commands, and in that case overhead of doing a hash function would probably cost you more than not having to do a switch. (Or have a *VERY* simple hash function)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that doing function calls instead of the switch would be faster (function calls have a significant overhead).  The switch should be compling to a jump-table anyway (GCC does this at least).

Comment: Cool, didn't know that about gcc, but anyways, one could define functions as inline, and instead of passing any arguments make them global variables and so on, making the function call overhead very small. Of course, when it comes to this level it's probably be easier to just code the whole thing in assembler. (If one knows how to do it.)

Comment: You can't inline calls made via a dispatch table. The closest option here is to use GCC label addresses, which would basically let you make your own inline functions in a jump table.

Comment: When calling a function purely by its address (i.e., through a function pointer), it's extremely unlikely that the call will be inlined.

Comment: Right, scratch that about inline functions.

Answer (score 1):

What's the architecture? You may get a speed-up with word-aligned opcodes, but it'll blow out your code size, which means you'll have to balance it against the cost of a cache miss.

Comment: x86_64. That would certainly balloon my code size, but the code is quite small.

Comment: On second thought this might not work since the code is interleaved with inline data (constants). To keep the alignment everything would have to grow to 8bytes. That'd be quite the cost (I'll try it anyway).

Comment: Hmm, shame. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score -1):

Few obvious optimization I see are,

1. If you don't use `cmd` anywhere than `switch()` then, directly use the pointer indirection, `switch( *code++ )`. For longer `while(true)` loop, this can be little helpful.
2. In `switch()`, you can use `continue` instead of `break`. Because when `continue` is used inside `if/else` or `switch`, compiler knows that execution has to jump to the outer loop; the same is not true for `break` (with respect to `switch`).
   Hope this helps.

Comment: Point 1 I tried before and it makes no difference (optimizer likely sees it the same). Point 2 I actually do, it appears to make a very slight difference (strange that the optimizer wouldn't do that on its own, but the time difference is so small it's hard to rule out statistical anomaly).